# question about curve secp112r1

Tags: elliptic-curves

In [SEC 2: Recommended Elliptic Curve Domain Parameters](http://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf) curve secp112r1 has $0xDB7C2ABF62E35E668076BEAD208B$ as the order of the finite field and as the $a$ coefficient in the equation $y^2 =x^3 +ax +b$. Wouldn't that essentially make the $a$ coefficient $0$? If so then why not just say that that's what the coefficient is?

secp192k1 has $0$ as coefficients so it's not like there's not precedent for a coefficient of $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misread the parameters: $p$ is $$\mathrm{0xDB7C2ABF62E35E668076BEAD208B} \text,$$ but $a$ is $$\mathrm{0xDB7C2ABF62E35E668076BEAD208\underline{\mathbf8}}$$
which is $-3$ $\bmod p$!